# «...раздельно(,) — кроме случаев...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Нужна запятая?

Вроде бы все мы помним, что «не» с глаголами нужно писать раздельно(,) — кроме случаев, когда слово без «не» неупотребимо.

Comment: А почему тире? На основе паузы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение нашлось вот [здесь](https://vk.com/@mogokru-ne-mnogie-ili-nemnogie-6-slov-kotorye-postoyanno-stavyat-nas):
*Вроде бы все мы помним, что «не» с глаголами нужно писать раздельно — кроме случаев, когда слово без «не» не употребляется.*

Думаю, что здесь можно рассмотреть вот эти рекомендации Розенталя:

> **2.** Условия, благоприятствующие постановке тире: <...>
> **6)** интонационное отделение главной части от следующей за ней придаточной: *Вы спросите — зачем я пошёл на это?*; *А вы уверены — нужно ли это?*..

Всё правильно: **интонационное** тире в предложении поставлено вместо запятой, поэтому еще одна запятая тут не требуется.

[Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так:

*Вроде бы все мы помним, что «не» с глаголами нужно писать раздельно, — **кроме случаев, когда слово без «не» неупотребимо.***

1. Мне не нравится **интонационное тире** вместо запятой. Это не правило, а всего лишь обозначение большей паузы. На самом деле запись **выглядит так**: *Вроде бы все мы помним, что «не» с глаголами нужно писать раздельно, кроме случаев, когда слово без «не» неупотребимо.*
2. Мне интересна сама конструкция. Здесь **три** предикативные основы, и это называется **сложная синтаксическая** конструкция. Знаки нужно ставить **[по правилу Лопатина.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)**
3. У нас **два блока** (СПП и простое предложение), причем в каждом из них есть свои знаки препинания. Нужно обозначить **отношения** между блоками. Второй блок **присоединяется** к первому, так это **дополнительное** сообщение. Одного тире недостаточно, поэтому ставим **единый знак** (запятая и тире).

При постановке единого знака бОльшая пауза, а также более наглядная графика. **Тире** — это не самый лучший знак для обозначения отношений между блоками.

4. Это действительно **решение задачи** (никаких лишних слов и рассуждений), Кроме того, **не надо искать** похожие и не очень похожие примеры, все по-честному (ни у кого не списываем). Поэтому мне очень нравится решать задачи **методом блоков.**

**P. S.** Если поставлено **тире**, то нужно объяснить этот знак тоже с помощью **блоков**. Нельзя решать задачу по этому правилу? Тогда мне хотелось бы узнать, **почему нельзя.**  Ведь там же три предикативные основы.

Comment: Что значит блокорешение задач? Надо писать *P. S.*, не *P.S.*

Comment: Это решение описано у Лопатина. Обычно предложение из нескольких основ делится на два блока, На стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании.  Именно эти отношения определяют и произношение. В речи мы тоже их обозначаем как основные.

Comment: Я не знаю, что и сказать. Где же-с правда-то?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы сторонники тире  доказали свою точку зрения и решили бы задачу через блоки. Какой вид отношений можно обозначить тире? Этот знак хорош в предложениях с двумя основами: "Вы спросите — зачем я пошёл на это?"  Две основы, изъясн. отношения.  "Кроме случаев, когда... "  - какая конструкция? Она присоединяется к СПП